# Is there any way I can get some parts of DataFrame from csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to split some part of DataFrame from csv.

I'd like to export only (17,A), (18,A) in the csv file. But The csv file is only one example. I mean, we only know about a1 and a2. a1 is always on (1,A) and a2 is on (random, A). so I have no clue about what position p and q are on it. Also, they might not be p and q. They are made like random alphabets.
**So I mean, the data I want are below a2 and I want to separate all the data above the first NaN value below a2.**

[image]

Comment: it seems you have to load all CSV to DataFrame and later you has to work with this DataFrame to get expected rows. like `df[ df["A"] == "p" ].index`

Comment: if this is really `CSV` then maybe read it as single string (using standard `open()`, `read()`) and split on empty lines - `split("\n\n")` and and get second element from list to get all text from `a2` to empty line. And you can save it as new CSV and read to DataFrame from file or you can try to use `io.StringIO(text)` to read it directly as `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))`